# IQueryable.Count for query involving navigation properties throws because they aren't loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Having a query that performs filtering that requires **Navigation Properties** which are explicitly included would not load them when the `.Count()` method is used on the query. Causing exceptions when the filtering expression in the `Where()` clauses run.

Changing the `.Count()` to `.ToList()` however would make Entity Framework include the referenced navigation properties and produces correct results

It seems that the `Count()` method ignores the **Navigation Properties** and their value is `null` in the filtering expression

My Project is using ASP Net Core 1.1 and EntityFramework 1.1.4

#### Sample Code

```
 public class ItemsService : IItemsService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public ItemsService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public ISearchResult Search(ISearchOptions options)
    {
        var query = this.dbContext.Item
                                  .Include(i => i.Vehicle)
                                  .Include(x => x.Part).ThenInclude(p => p.PartCategory)
                                  .Where(i => i.IsDeleted == false);

        query = this.ApplyMakeFiltering(query, options.Make);
        query = this.ApplyModelFiltering(query, options.Model);

        var total = query.Count(); // Throws => NavigationProperty Vehicle is null
        var total2 = query.ToList().Count; // Works Correctly

        return new SearchResult(options, query, total);

    }

    private IQueryable<Item> ApplyMakeFiltering(IQueryable<Item> query, string make)
    {
        return this.Filter(
            query,
            make,                     // item.Vehicle is null for `Count()` but set correctly for `ToList()`
            item => this.StringMatches(item.Vehicle.CustomVehicleMakeName, make));
    }

    private IQueryable<Item> ApplyModelFiltering(IQueryable<Item> query, string model)
    {
        return this.Filter(
            query,
            model,
            item => this.StringMatches(item.Vehicle.CustomVehicleModelName, model));
    }

    private IQueryable<Item> Filter<T>(IQueryable<Item> query, T expected, Predicate<Item> matcher)
    {
        if (expected == null) return query;

        return query.Where(item => matcher(item));
    }

    private bool StringMatches(string a, string b)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)) return false;

        return a.Equals(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to obtain the count of matched results after filtering?

Comment: if `item.Vehicle` is null, you can not use `item.Vehicle.CustomVehicleMakeName` or throw an exception as it is occurring, in VS 2017 i think you can use a null coalesce `(item.Vehicle?.CustomVehicleMakeName ?? "", make)` (not sure if can use it in a filter)

Comment: @CelsoLívero problem is that it is should not be null. because when he calls `ToList()` than it works.

Comment: I had not seen the line below.

Comment: Are you aware that whole filtering is performed in memory and not in database here?

Comment: @Evk Oh, and that's probably the reason the `Count` method doesn't work for me. My filtering methods cannot be mapped to sql expressions , right ?
I'll have to checkout the query that is created by EF to verify that

Comment: Yes that is the reason. When Count executes, it needs to create sql query. Includes are ignored because for Count they do not make any sense. Then part of your expression is converted to sql and part is executed in memory. There is a setting for EF Core to prevent in memory execution and throw exception instead - I recommend enable that.